# JQuery Error Comparing Strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jquery function but its throwing an error on the if statement: `TypeError: elem.nodeName is undefined`

When i output the console.log outside of the if statement it's working fine?

```
 <input type="radio" name="contact" value="email">email
<input type="radio" name="contact" value="tel">tel
<input type="radio" name="contact" value="writing">writing

$(function() {
 var myListRef = {'email':'email','tel':'tel','writing':'writing'}
 $('[name="contact"]').click(function() {

    $.each( myListRef , function( key, value ) {
        if(value !== $(this).val()) {
            console.log($(this).val()); 
        }    
    });

 });
});
```

What I'm i doing wrong with the if statement?

Comment: The value of `this` changes inside the `$.each` - save it outside in a variable in the event handler and compare it to the cached value

Comment: *I have the following jquery function* - what do you think a jquery function is?

Comment: @amit. please explain.

Comment: jQuery is a library. It includes various useful objects that can be used to manipulate DOM (mostly, but not solely). It is not a language and doesn't define statements, expressions or anything of that sort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were changing the scope with the each... save `this` before the loop

```
$('[name="contact"]').click(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    $.each(myListRef, function (key, value) {
        if (value !== $this.val()) {
            console.log($this.val());
        }
    });

});
```